# How to pass path variable in Thymeleaf from controller

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I know there is a lot of answers about this, but I have no luck trying any of them.

Here is my controller:

```
  @PostMapping("/savedAdventureHolidays/{postId}/post")
public UserProfile saveHoliday(@PathVariable(value = "postId") String postId,
                                 @Valid @RequestBody UserProfile comment, Model model) {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String username = authentication.getName();

    return adventureHolidaysRepository.findById(postId).map(post -> {
        comment.setAdventureHolidaysList(Collections.singletonList(post));
        comment.setLoggedUserId(username);
        model.addAttribute("comment", comment);
        return userProfileRepository.save(comment);
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("PostId " + postId + " not found"));
}
```

Now I want to create a button so when user click on it controller should be called with path variable

Last one try was something like this:

```
<form th:action="@{/api/userProfile/savedAdventureHolidays/{id}/post(id=${postId})}">
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/></form>
```

But I got

```
The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String "//"
```

Also I tried with

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/api/userProfile/savedAdventureHolidays/{postId}/post(id=${postId})}">
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/></form>
```

But then I got

```
    There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415).
Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your mixing MVC controllers with Rest controllers (or something else).

If you are using Thymeleaf, it is based on MVC controllers and will expect the Controller to return a string mapped to a template file (or a ModelAndView).

The controller should look something like:

```
// To load the view with the post form
@RequestMapping(value = "/userProfile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showForm() {
    return new ModelAndView("userProfile", "userProfile", new UserProfile());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/savedAdventureHolidays/{postId}/post", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userProfile")UserProfile userProfile, 
  BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "error"; // an error page (might skip)
    }
    UserProfile updatedUserProfile = adventureHolidaysRepository.findById(postId).map(post -> {
      comment.setAdventureHolidaysList(Collections.singletonList(post));
      comment.setLoggedUserId(username);
      model.addAttribute("comment", comment);
      return userProfileRepository.save(comment);
    })
    model.addAttribute("userProfile", updateUserProfile);
    return "viewTemplateAfterPost"; // update this to correct view after post
}
```

then the form tag in Thymeleaf might look like

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/api/userProfile/savedAdventureHolidays/{postId}/post}" modelAttribute="userProfile">
  <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```